# What is a linearly independent solution for a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, independence

I read in text as well as many places in internet that, for a given differential equation, if $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are solutions, then $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are linearly independent solutions only iff $$c_1*y_1(x) + c_2*y_2(x) = 0 $$ for $c_1=c_2=0$ only.  
If the above equation is satisfied for $c_1 \neq 0$ and $c_2=0$, then are $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ linearly independent solutions? 
To summarize, what should be the condition for linearly independent solutions? $$c_1=0 \&\& c_2=0$$ or $$c_1=0 \| c_2=0$$

Comment: Well, how is linear independence defined...?

Comment: If $c_1 \neq 0$ and $c_2=0$ then $y_1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make any sense to consider $c_1\neq0$ and $c_2=0$. Let me explain what I mean by this.

If we consider the the case that $c_1\neq0$ and $c_2=0$, then, the equation will be,

\begin{align}  &c_1*y_1(x)=0 \\\\  \implies &y_1(x)=0\end{align}

Which means you're finding the roots of the function $y_1$. This is in no way related to the question of linear Independence. Hence the argument to consider one of them equal to zero, and the other non zero, fails.

Comment: It does not mean that you're finding the roots of $y_1$, it means that the function $y_1$ must be identically zero.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$ of a given differential equation are defined to be linearly dependent if one is a constant multiple of the other. In your example, if the equation
$$c_{1}*y_{1}(x)+c_{2}*y_{2}(x)=0\tag{1}\label{1}$$
is satisfied for some $c_{1}\neq 0$ and $c_{2}=0$, then we see that by definition $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$ are linearly dependent, since
$$y_{1}(x)=-\frac{c_{2}}{c_{1}}y_{2}(x),$$
and $-\frac{c_{2}}{c_{1}}$ is a constant multiple of $y_{2}(x)$ (namely, it is the constant $0$).

Any two functions $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$ satisfy $\eqref{1}$ for $c_{1}=c_{2}=0.$ Note that the procedure above for showing that $y_{1}(x)$ is a constant multiple of $y_{2}(x)$ does not work under this choice of constants, since it would require dividing both sides by zero. Thus, if $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$ are functions such that $\eqref{1}$ is **only** satisfied by the particular choice of constants $c_{1}=c_{2}=0,$ then the solutions are not constant multiples of each other, and they are called linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

You just stated that the condition is that *both* $c_1$ and  $c_2$ must be zero when $c_1\cdot y_1 (x)+c_2\cdot y_2 (x)=0$...  that is only the *trivial* linear combination is zero...

Note :  this is the same as in the case of vectors. ..